# Bash loop to make directories in every child directory

Tags: bash, loops, directory

I want to make 2 directories in every child directory (basically a nested loop).
AKA: I want to create 2 folders {trimmed,original} in each of the audio and video folders [current folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMTBe.png)

I tried the following bash command:

```
for dir in */; do
for dir in */; do
mkdir -- "$dir"/{Trimmed,Original}; 
done
done
```

But that code put a two folders in each parent folder (Cog and Personality) but did no put any folders in the child directories (AudioCog, VideoCog, AudioPersonality, VideoPersonality)

Comment: I'm surprised `rm -r` created any directories at all, but it sounds like you wanted a single `for dir in */*/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This isn't how Bash variable scope works - the inner loop overwrites the value of `dir` from the outer loop.
2. Neither does `for dir in */` actually *enter* that directory, so all you're achieving with the double loop is going through every directory in . N times, once for each subdirectory. As [@thatotherguy wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51868447/bash-loop-to-make-directories-in-every-child-directory/51869422#comment90689420_51868447), you want `for dir in */*/`.
3. `rm` does not create any directories. You'll need `mkdir` for that.

Answer (score 1):

Other possible way using arrays and [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
f=(./*/*/); mkdir "${f[@]/%/original}" "${f[@]/%/trimmed}"
```

Or using `find`:

```
find . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -exec mkdir {}/{original,trimmed} \;
```